# Android bitmap/ byte array memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am having problems with a memory leak in my android app. Based on my hprof analysis it appears to be caused by a `byte` array that comes from a `Bitmap` in a `SurfaceView` class.

Here is the MAT analysis of one of several arrays:

[image: MAT Analysis]

and the code of the offending class:

```
public class AndroidFastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    AndroidGame game;
    Bitmap framebuffer;
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public AndroidFastRenderView(AndroidGame game, Bitmap framebuffer) {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;
        this.framebuffer = framebuffer;
        this.holder = getHolder();
        this.holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        setSystemUiVisibility(
                SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    }

    public void resume() {
        setSystemUiVisibility(
                SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        Rect dstRect = new Rect();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (running) {
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 10000000.000f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            game.getCurrentScreen().update(deltaTime);
            game.getCurrentScreen().paint(deltaTime);
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);
            canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        running = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        getHolder().getSurface().release();
        framebuffer.recycle();
    }
}
```

`release()` is called in my Activity's `onDestroy()`.

`frameBuffer` is created with the line:

```
Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, ARGB_8888);
```

in my Activity.

Comment: Is the framebuffer bitmap being pixel modified ? or is it being created new every frame ? The code provided doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: So, is the framebuffer created anew every frame ?

Comment: @S.D. Are you saying a change needs to be made in the Activity class? I tried recycling at the end of the onCreate() method, but that caused an exception so I made frameBuffer an instance variable and recycled it in the onDestroy(). Ran without error, but the problem persists.

Comment: Debug breakpoint at `Bitmap.createBitmap` line and see how many times it runs in lifecycle of the activity. Does it runs repeatedly ?

Comment: @S.D. the breakpoint is only triggered when the Activity is created. The problem is that everytime the activity is created memory usage jumps with no decrease in memory when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: The Bitmap you're showing in the MAT analysis is held by the Canvas (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#67), which is stored in the `frameBuffer` member, which is part of your SurfaceView subclass, which is held in a local variable. If there's a leak, it's in the handling of the SurfaceView subclass instance. (FWIW, it's generally best to make SurfaceView a member rather than subclassing it, unless you're planning to draw on both the View and the Surface.)

Comment: @fadden does something need to be done to my `SurfaceView` in `onDestroy` other than calling the `release()` method?

Comment: If your Activity is destroyed, there should be no references to the SurfaceView, and no need to explicitly do anything. It should not be reachable from the GC root set (thread stacks, class statics, JNI globals, etc). If the SurfaceView is still reachable after the Activity is destroyed, then that's a problem, and MAT should help make clear how that reference still exists. (cf. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: @fadden which option in MAT can I use to figure out what's keeping it alive?

Comment: Just look at the object chain for each object. In the screen shot you posted, "Thread-391" is keeping that specific instance around.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure your Thread "renderThread" is stopped. If it is still active, it holds a reference to the "AndroidFastRenderView" object so it can't free the memory...

Comment: interrupt should not be deprecated:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

Comment: you're right sorry about that, but `interrupt()` did not fix the problem either

Comment: `interrupt()` does not stop a thread. You stop the thread by asking it to stop, which it does by returning from `run()`. All `interrupt()` accomplishes is to wake it up if it's waiting / sleeping. The `pause()` function in the posted code looks fine -- just make sure that it's actually getting called.